# If $|\dot{x}(t)|$ exponentially converges to $0$ as $t\to\infty$, can we prove the existence of $\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)$?

Tags: analysis

If $\lim_{t \to \infty} \dot{x}(t)=0$ and $|\dot{x}(t)|$ exponentially converges to $0$ (i.e., there exist the positive constants $c_1$ and $c_2$, such that $|\dot{x}(t)|\leq c_1e^{-c_2~t}$, $t\geq 0$), can we prove the existence of $\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It is time to unleash the power of the fundamental theorem of calculus. This will give you that $(x(n))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy. Then finish with another application of the fundamental theorem of calculus. Pat your back and have a soda :)

Comment: hell have a beer if you like

Comment: Thanks Severin Schraven for your hints. Can you please explain more?

Comment: @CUG Something like this maybe: $| x(t) - x(s) | = | \int_s^t \dot{x}(r) \, dr | \leq \int_s^t |\dot{x}(r)| \, dr$.

Comment: @ Charles Hudgins Thanks a lot! I know how to prove it. We can first prove $\int_{0}^{+\infty}|\dot{x}(t)|dt<\infty$ (absolute convergence), which implies  $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\dot{x}(t) dt<\infty$. Thus, $x(t)$ is convergent as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: @CUG In order to ping somebody, you should not leave white space between @ and the name :) your proof works nicely. In fact even better, then what I had in mind.

Comment: @Severin Schraven Thank you very much:)